# How to execute joins of an entity with the result of a query in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I want to run the following SQL in hibernate:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, ipc.total 
FROM Category c,
(
    SELECT comm.category.id as id, count(*) as total 
    FROM Commerce as comm 
    GROUP BY comm.category.id 
) ipc 
WHERE c.id = ipc.id
```

This is my attempt to write that one in JQL but I get an error. It doesn't seem to like my join against a query result.

Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 86 [SELECT c.id, c.name, ipc.total FROM com.brujulasolutions.directorio.model.Category c,( SELECT comm.category.id as id, count(*) as total FROM com.brujulasolutions.directorio.model.Commerce as comm GROUP BY comm.category.id ) ipc WHERE c.id = ipc.id]

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, ipc.total 
FROM Category c,
(
    SELECT comm.category.id as id, count(*) as total 
    FROM Commerce as comm 
    GROUP BY comm.category.id 
) ipc 
WHERE c.id = ipc.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate query language does not directly support this type of update join.  Instead, we can use a correlated subquery in the select clause:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Commerce AS comm
        WHERE comm.category.id = c.id) AS total
FROM Category c
```

Comment: That worked, thanks mate. I cannot give you a like though, not enough Qi lol. It sucks when a tool cuts out the possibilities of another broader one one like in this case. Specially when I know I don't care about the what if you change the DB some day. I actually have never seen a company doing so, it so costly that I think very use cases will require that.